# Bootstrap Glyphicons/Navigation Icons

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot figure out how to get the text in the p tags to fit inside the navigation icons (using Bootstrap glyphicons). Here is how I am using it:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <p>January, 2016</p>

    </div><!--this ends the header div-->
```

January, 2016 appears below the navigation icons instead of in between the left and right arrows. Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <p>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span>January, 2016</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </p>
</div><!--this ends the header div-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text `January 2016` in between the `spans` like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>January, 2016
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/i35xsLvdZj) for the same.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be its helps you..

**Method-1**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">January, 2016</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Method-2**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>January, 2016
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Method-3**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
     <span>January, 2016</span>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</div>
```